# await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); not working

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

What is wrong with this code? _context.Images.Add(image) works but await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); doesn't work. There is no error/exception. A row is created in the database table but the BLOB column is empty. When I add the blob value manually in the database I can see this value in the blob column. I am using .NET 8 / EF Core 8 / MySQL 8

Page Model:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{

    private readonly WebAppContext _context;
    
    public IndexModel(WebAppContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUploadImage([FromBody] string imageBlob)
    {
        try
        {
            Image image = new Image
            {
                ImageBlob = Convert.FromBase64String(imageBlob)
            };

            _context.Images.Add(image);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return new JsonResult(Convert.ToBase64String(image.ImageBlob));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error uploading image: " + ex.Message);
            return StatusCode(500, "Error uploading image.");
        }
    }
```

DbContext:

```
public class WebAppContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }

    public WebAppContext(DbContextOptions<WebAppContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }   
}
```

[image: img]

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work", does your app crash, do you have any logs ? Provide more detailed information

Comment: There is no error/exception. A row is created in the database table but the BLOB column is empty. When I add the blob value manually in the database I can see this value in the blob column.

Comment: Use Pomelo provider. Official MySql EF Core provider has problems with blobs and is unstable.

Comment: It worked! I can't thank you enough. @SvyatoslavDanyliv